# Notification when user try to close browser or tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ajax, jquery-ui

My script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var hook = true;
      window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        if (hook) {
          return "Do you sure what to leave"
        }
      }
      function unhook() {
        hook=false;
      }
    </script>
```

This code blocks user when

- User try to close browser or tab
- When user clicked external link
- When user clicked internal link
- When user refresh the page

> I only want to block user when they try to close browser or tab.

Comment: @Sunul, you can use window.onbeforeunload.

window.onload = function () {
        var btnRelease = document.getElementById('<%= btnRelease.ClientID %>');
        function setGlobal() {
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
        }
    };
    window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
        var message = 'Changes will be lost and would you like to proceed.';
        if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
            event = window.event;
        }
        if (event) {
            event.returnValue = message;
        }
        return message;
    };

Answer (score 1):

This is normally used to prevent users lost their drafts from unexpected page leave actions, so normally we will only set this up when user typed something in a input/textarea etc..., and it's predictable user action (cause we can detect if user entered anything or not).

But, you want to block user only when they're trying to close browser or tab, this is not a predictable action, and it cannot always be detectable (such like closing browser).

So, if you want to do so, I think you need to attach listeners to any other acceptable page leave actions (like those you mentioned), and cancel blocking by returning null/false in `onbeforeunload`.

For example, this accept link redirects:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = () => true;

document
  .querySelectorAll("a")
  .forEach((element) =>
    element.addEventListener(
      "click",
      () => (window.onbeforeunload = null)
    )
  );
```

I don't know how to detect page reload, maybe by detecting F5 button is pressed or not? but this can't know if user manually click refresh button on browser.

Btw, you should really reconsider that why you would like to do that, cause if it's not for prevent users from lose their drafts, then I think it's not a user-friendly action.

Comment: atleast how you exclude some div from the JS. if anything clicked inside the particular div. it should not blocked.?

Comment: well... In my case, I'll judge if the target element of MouseEvent is the element or not. In other words, only clicked the correct target could trigger it.